# Using more than one Custom Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-authentication

I'm working on a project where we're in the process of tightening up the security within an area (module) of our site.  We have 5 modules altogether, with all 5 currently sharing the same Custom Authorize Attribute class that does three checks.

1. Did you agree to the acceptance terms?  Yes, proceed to 2.  No, you are unauthorized and thrown to an unauthorized page.
2. Are you a member of the site?  Yes, proceed to 3.  No, you are unauthorized and thrown to an unauthorized page.
3. Is your role allowed in this module?  Yes, proceed onwards.  No, you are unauthorized and thrown to an unauthorized page.

The classes for the 5 modules currently are decorated by this Custom Authorize Attribute, with their individual role(s) checked (3/5 modules have one individual role, whereas 2 others has multiple, with one having 4, and the one I'm posting about has 3 now).  However, with us tightening security in 1 module, it has become a question on how to go about it.  This module we're changing has 3 roles (Read-Only, User, Admin).

- Read-Only: sounds like it is.  No Add/Edit/Delete privileges.
- User: has read access and can Add/Edit/Delete pending other permissions check.
- Admin: do as you please.  You can Add/Edit/Delete and get into Admin only areas.

User is a special case altogether too due that it has a secondary set of checks, which includes checking permissions in up to 2 other lists (always check one of the two lists, while the other is for one select area).

My question is, since this security is outside of the original Custom Authorize Attribute and hinges on this one module, should I create a new Custom Authorize Attribute, or should I modify the original?

My initial thoughts were to remove the class wide decoration of this module and instead apply it to each method.  Going this route would lend itself more to adding the new logic to the current Custom Authorize Attribute.

However, there is an issue there.  Doing this for an Admin and Read-Only User works out fine, but it is the User case that is the problem.  The User has to do a secondary check to see if they have permissions to the specific record they are about to look at.  If they do not, they are allowed there like a Read-Only user, but cannot edit.

Due to that clause, I'm slightly unsure on whether to have a private method that does the checking versus the Custom Authorize Attribute.

Any direction or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much thought on this, I came up with the following solution.  I did not add to the current Custom Authorize Attribute I had because this is exclusive to only one module within the site.

However, I do run checks on all pages that the user can hit (barring the Post methods) to determine all cases.

When a user is an Admin, they are given Modify Access.  When they are a Read-Only User, they are given no Modify Access.  When they are a User, they are checked for Permissions as well, and if they have those Permissions, they are given Modify Access.  Otherwise, they are treated like a Read-Only User.

I stored the user's roles and Permissions, as well as if they have Modify Access, within Session.  Should the Session(s) not be found, I go back out and add them back in.  I also update kill those Sessions if a user's Roles/Permissions are updated in the User Admin area.

Also, in pages that modify something (Add/Edit/Delete), I added a chunk of logic that if they have no Modify Access, they are booted to an Unauthorized Access page.

So far, this seems to have worked out well and has had no issues thus far.  I would have much rather added this logic in one place like the Custom Authorize Attribute class, but at the same time, I think it would have been inappropriate to place it there due that it was for only one Module.  Thanks.